# Spark Remove Line (Python)

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have a dataset that I am running statistical functions on and that I need to potentially remove the first and last line (depending on if there is a header trailer). What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

```
dataSplit = sc.textFile(inputFile).map(lambda line: line.split(","))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just a beginner with spark, but I guess this would work. Please correct me, if it doesn't work or there are any better practices.

```
# get file
inputRDD = sc.textFile(inputFile).cache()

# get header
header = inputRDD.first()

# get trailer, but be careful with large RDDs and collect()!
trailer = inputRDD.collect()[-1]

# remove header trailer 
filtered_inputRDD = inputRDD.filter(lambda x: x != header).filter(lambda x: x != trailer)

# afterwards you can split 
dataSplit = filtered_inputRDD.map(lambda line: line.split(","))
```

I tried something different to get the trailer in a more efficient way:

```
# this is a helper function which iterates through
# the part it gets and returns the last item of the part
# 
# item is set to "empty" in case part is empty
# replace it with desired output for empty parts
def iterate(part):
    item = "empty"
    my_iter = iter(part)
    for item in my_iter:
        pass
    return item

# instead of collecting the RDD and returning the last item
# it now does a mapPartitions first and iterates through every part
# and returns the last items of every partition
# then you only have to collect [numPartitions] rows and the 
# selection of the last item is much easier
trailer_efficient = inputRDD.mapPartitions(lambda x: [iterate(x)]).collect()[-1]
```

Comment: The header part works great but the problem is I am using 10GB+ RDD's and the trailer with the .collect() won't work out well, its very expensive todo.